# Database Statistics tools

Tags: database, postgresql

I have to monitor database statistic for postgresql.In future it may change.So the tool which support multiple database server would be better.
The statistics  are like : 
1.  Query execution time.
2.  Number of queries that are executed per sec.
3.  Number of queries are still in execution.
4.  Ram usage of the query utlitization.

If any module available to integrate in my applications??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any open source module, which really meet your requirements (especially real-time analyzing), but you might take a look at comercial product [Postgres Plus® HQ Monitoring](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-plus-hq).

Another attempt is to set log_duration and log_statement parameters and anylyze logfiles. For example you can use CSV format and load data back to server or use ordinary format with [pgFouine](http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/) (a PostgreSQL log analyzer).

To get currently executed queries you can use pg_stat_activity view. I have no idea how to obtain their memory usage.